# Shopify Math logic not working properly

Tags: shopify

on my  store when using custom template i got a price based on some values

Price * 2 it works

Example.

17.99 * 2

I got in cart: 35.98, this is good.

But when using:

17.99 * 0.5, should be 8.99

i got: 17.99

Why?????????? Any ideas?

Im adding as value this way:

```
<option value="{{ qty | times:0.50 }}" data-qua="{{ qty | times:0.50   }}">{{ inches }}m</option>
```

Well, i have found that due to a Shopify limitation you can not use decimals as quantity, so cannot do PRICE * 0.5

If is there a any solution to this let me know.

Comment: You have to look into discounts. What you trying to achieve is not possible in Shopify. Quantity should be used as quantity and not as a price discount functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sell by unit pricing. As you figured out, no shopping cart lets you sell 0.3456 of something. While you can buy .0005342 of a bitcoin, you cannot sell non-integer anything with Shopify. So adjust your formula to sell 1 thing at $.003456 or whatever... and collect your fortune that way.

Comment: This make no sense, i was able to sell on non-integer with Magento, so this is only a Shopify limitation, no dev limitation, there is no reason to limit such thing.

Comment: Semantics. You think you can sell a fraction of something, but the reality is you are selling an integer multiple of something. It is not a limitation of Shopify to maintain an integer quantity, but more one of imagination in selling things.

Comment: No sir, in fabrics you sell with decimals, dog food also, by kg, Shopify should allow to sell products in the way the client want!, a family of mine sell in decimals, so he should be able to do the same online, we will move to Magento, thank you.

Comment: Good luck. Magento works the same way, but you'll figure that out once you dig in. Enjoy the extra work too, security flaws and hosting responsibilities!

Comment: Im already using Magento on that way, it has all the security work flow it needs, zero problems at this moment, thank you!

Comment: On real life you have security issues too!, a guy can came into your store with a gun and ask you for all the money, there are always issues, but you need to allow your client to sell in the way they need, in real life they sell on decimals, you can not tell them how to manage their business, this is a Shopify fault. Im sorry, It worked on Magento.

Comment: A cursory glance shows Magento support of decimal quantities is a joke. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5570  shows it can be done, but not without amateur hour hacking. As long as you like that, you can make money with it. Shopify does not support that as it is a terrible hack job to support. Magento just proves it. Just because it can be done one way, does not imply that way is clean, or reliable.

Comment: I have made my own function, thak you David, no worries.

Comment: I was able to do it with Shopify as well with line_item

Comment: what does that mean, with line_item? You mean using regular integer quantity, decimal unit values and then storing actual measures in line item properties? Of course that works... but you knew that already.

Comment: No, i have created a dropdown when end user select the qty, then via ajax api i update the price and send to the cart

Comment: Send me the link to your shop so I can show you how easy it is for you lose money :)